# Summing XML Data in MSWord Mail Merge

Tags: xpath, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a report card written in Word that uses an XML file for its input.  In the XML file, if a student remains in the same section all three trimesters there will be one node for that class; if they change sections at the trimester they'll have one node for each section.  The nodes look something like this (greatly simplified):

```
<ReportCardSectionFB Abs1="2" Abs2="11" CourseID="ELMATH1" CourseTitle="Math" PeriodStart="3" TeacherName="Jones, Jennifer" TermCode="Year" SectionID="ELMATH1-4" />

<ReportCardSectionFB Abs1="1.50" Abs2="6" CourseID="ELMATH1" CourseTitle="Math" PeriodStart="3" TeacherName="Smith, Tina" TermCode="Year" SectionID="ELMATH1-3" />
```

There is no indicator within the XML as to which trimester the node belongs to.

In the Word document, we're pulling the absence data with the following mail merge command:

```
{MERGEFIELD  "ReportCardSectionFB[@PeriodStart='3']/ @Abs1" \# 0.#  \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

That's not working in this situation: it only gets the absence data from the first node it comes across, i.e.: `2.0`.  Is there a way to get the sum of @Abs1 for all period 3 classes, i.e.: `3.5`?  If not, is there a way to only get the last @Abs1 for period 3, i.e.: `1.5`?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the entire xpath in `sum()`?

Comment: I get various errors, depending on where I place the sum() (around the entire XPath expression, just around the @Abs1, etc.).  Any recommendations for where the function should go?

Comment: The correct xpath 1.0 expression would be `sum()` around the entire xpath, as I said : `sum(ReportCardSectionFB[@PeriodStart='3']/@Abs1)`. Also see [the demo](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/0I6Bg6Q4J) in an xpath tester

Comment: It looks like the XPath engine in Word or Synergy (the program that's using the Word document to do the mail merge) is limited, then, because I get the following error when I wrap it with sum(): "Error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this 3rd party product, which can use xml as input and is capable of merging it with MS Word template. I is also much more powerful than the built-in Word's mail merge. You can see some examples [here](http://www.docentric.com/product/how-to-use).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try summing the absences in Synergy - there's a new checkbox under AttDef1, 2, etc.  that adds up all the absences for the data range - Include all day data for the entire date range regardless of section enrollment or section timeframe.  That way the absences should be the same for each section, if that works for your district.

You can also try the SET function in Word to nest the MERGEFIELDS as bookmarks and use the Word operator functions to then add the bookmarks.